# INSERT into database using multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I got array like this :

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
     (
       [0] => A
       [1] => 1
       [2] => Too High
     )
  [1] => Array
     (
       [0] => AB
       [1] => 7
       [2] => OK
     )
   [2] => Array
     (
       [0] => B
       [1] => 10
       [2] => Too High
      )
)
```

I'm trying to insert array above into my db using this code, i want to do it without column name, because the column could be changed anytime (user can add new field into table), array lengths is same with the amount of fields :

```
if(is_array($FINALRESULT)) {
    $queryi = "INSERT INTO tempresult VALUES ";

    $value = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i) {
       for ($j=0; $j < 3; $j++) { 
          $value[] = mysql_real_escape_string("($FINALRESULT[$j])");
       }
    }
    $queryi .= implode(',', $value);

    mysql_query($queryi) or exit(mysql_error()); 
}
```

But i got notice like these :

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Livestockmapping(edit)\dsssawprocess.php on line 104 
>   Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

Comment: Please start using `mysqli_*` or `PDO` as `mysql_*` is deprecated and is removed in PHP7

Comment: @SuperDJ Ah I see, thank you for your advice.

Comment: you are trying to insert an array into a string, you need to use either implode, json_encode or serialize in order to convert from array to stirng. Moreover, when you will get the data from the database you must convert the data back to array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
$FINALRESULT = [
    ['A', 1, 'Too High'],
    ['AB', 7, 'OK'],
    ['B', 10, 'Too High'],
];

$all_values = [];
$query = "INSERT INTO tempresult VALUES ";

foreach($FINALRESULT as $key) {
    $row_values = [];
    foreach($key as $s_key => $s_value) {
        $row_values[] = '"'.$s_value.'"';
    }
    $all_values[] = '('.implode(',', $row_values).')';
}

//Implode all rows
$query .= implode(',', $all_values);

echo $query;
```

**Result:**

```
INSERT INTO tempresult VALUES ("A","1","Too High"), ("AB","7","OK"), ("B","10","Too High")
```

Also use PDO and prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

In your code you need `$FINALRESULT[$i][$j]` because it's a 2 level array.

Comment: I just tried yours, and it appears this error (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'high..), I have tried using `$FINALRESULT[$i][$j]` but no luck..

Comment: Ok, I had the parenthesis in the wrong place. Try this one.

Comment: i just tried it again, and there's no error. But the `tempresult` table still empty, which is the data not inserted..

Comment: I'm pretty sure that yours should work. But I don't know where the mistake why the data inserted

Comment: Sorry, it should produced an error because of the string values. Well, give the above a try. Now it will work (I hope).

Comment: You are welcome. But you really have to use prepared statements to avoid SQL Injections and because mysql_* functions are deprecated. You can use mysqli instead or even better PDO.